# How long after your domain expires do you have to re-register it before someone else can?

Tags: domain-registration

Can you register an expired domain immediately after it expires, or is there a waiting period?

(I'm sure this can be found on google, but I don't know the proper name for it. :( )

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your domain registrar. Generally what they do is provide a 15 day grace period before which you have to renew your domain. If you have not, then the domain registrar will either continue to own the domain (and show ads) or de-register. So it depends on when the registrar de-registers the domain. If it is not de-registered, then that domain can be purchased only from that registrar.

Comment: In addition, reinstating recently expired domain is often significantly more expensive than renewing on time.