# What happens when a domain name reached it's expiration date?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [when does a domain name really expire before someone else can register it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20309/when-does-a-domain-name-really-expire-before-someone-else-can-register-it)

As my title says, my question is when can I buy a domain name when it will be expired in the next days ?

The Registrar is NameBright.com